# 2 $(…).datepicker is not a function error

Tags: jquery

i include this link on page but not working this load page

```
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.2/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />

    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.2/jquery-ui.js" type="text/javascript"></script>


<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
    $(function() {
        $("#datepicker1").datepicker({});
    });
    enter code here

</script>
</head>
```

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that maybe some of the JS scripts have not finished loading before you try to call the datepicker.  Try making the call to datepicker *after* the page has finished loading completely:

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
    $( window ).load(function() {
        $("#datepicker1").datepicker({});
    });

    // more code here

</script>
```

Comment: just a quick question. i thought `$(document).ready` is the moment when the DOM is ready to be changed  , and `$(window).load` is after the whole page with all the content elements ( images, iframes etc. )  is loaded completely. so...maybe it would be wiser to use `window.load()` in this case ? so the `datepicker` is fired after everything is loaded?

Comment: @MihaiT Thanks for pointing this out, and I agree completely with you.  Alas, my answer still might not solve his problem, but it is one stone to turn over.